# Move multiple CCSprite across the screen Cocos2dx

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x, game-physics, ccaction, flappy-bird-clone

I have an Init method and spawn() method which is called by a CCAction every 2 seconds! 
What i want is to move `pipePair` node across the screen every 2 seconds, something like in the flappy bird game! But in my case am not able to add multiple pairs of the node in the screen plus the speed of the MoveBy `CCAction` fastens periodically.

So i want the nodes should be added periodically and they should move in a constant speed across the screen.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
bool HelloWorld::init()
{

//creating the world

b2Vec2 gravity;
gravity.Set(0.0f, -20.0f);
world = new b2World(gravity);

// Do we want to let bodies sleep?
world->SetAllowSleeping(true);

world->SetContinuousPhysics(true);

setAccelerometerEnabled( true );
scheduleUpdate();
setTouchEnabled(true);
//////////////////////////////
// 1. super init first
if( !CCLayerColor::initWithColor(ccc4(255, 255, 255, 255)) ) //RGBA
{
    return false;
}
if ( !CCLayer::init() )
{
    return false;
}

screenSize = CCDirector::sharedDirector()->getWinSize();

//Initializing CCNodes

_moving = CCNode::create();
addChild(_moving);
_pipes = CCNode::create();
_moving->addChild(_pipes);


CCSprite *test = CCSprite::create("goalssss.png");
CCRect rectOfPipe =  test->boundingBox();

float64 distanceToMove = screenSize.width + 2.5*rectOfPipe.size.width;
CCMoveBy* movePipes = CCMoveBy::create(0.01*distanceToMove, CCPointMake(-screenSize.width, 0));
CCRemoveSelf *removePipes = CCRemoveSelf::create();
sequenceActionOfPipes = CCSequence::create(movePipes,removePipes);
sequenceActionOfPipes->retain();

CCCallFunc *spawn = CCCallFunc::create(this, callfunc_selector(HelloWorld::spawnPipes));
CCDelayTime *delayForTwoSecs = CCDelayTime::create(2.0);
CCSequence *sequenceForSpawnAndDelay = CCSequence::create(spawn,delayForTwoSecs);
CCRepeatForever *repeatActionForeverOfSpawnAndDelay =  CCRepeatForever::create(sequenceForSpawnAndDelay);
this->runAction(repeatActionForeverOfSpawnAndDelay);`
}
```

This is my spawn method which is called every 2 seconds!

```
void HelloWorld::spawnPipes(){

CCNode *pipePair = CCNode::create();
pipePair->setPosition(CCPoint(screenSize.width, 0));
//pipePair->setZOrder(-10);

float64 randomVal = arc4random()%(int32)(screenSize.height/3);

CCSprite *_pipeUpReplica = CCSprite::create("goalssss.png");
_pipeUpReplica->setPosition(CCPoint(20, randomVal));

CCSprite *_pipeBelowReplica = CCSprite::create("goalssss.png");
_pipeBelowReplica->setPosition(CCPoint(20, randomVal+100+_pipeUpReplica->boundingBox().size.height));
pipePair->addChild(_pipeUpReplica);
pipePair->addChild(_pipeBelowReplica);

//run actions
pipePair->runAction(sequenceActionOfPipes);
_pipes->addChild(pipePair);

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firs of all, you don't need to do this :

```
if( !CCLayerColor::initWithColor(ccc4(255, 255, 255, 255)) ) //RGBA
{
    return false;
}
if ( !CCLayer::init() )
{
    return false;
}
```

`CCLayerColor` inherits from CCLayer (reference : [docs](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/reference/native-cpp/V2.2.3/da/d2c/classcocos2d_1_1_c_c_layer_color.html)) and I certainly hope you don;t inherit from both of them! :)

As to the problem at hand, I can't pinpoit a problem, but I can spot some possible pitfalls, which may be contrbuting to your issues.

1. A lot of nodes. You have your Layer, on which you add the `_moving` node on which you add the `_pipes` node on which you add the `pipePair` node. Unless they are essential for other things in your game, I can;t see a reason why you are not adding the `pipePair` directly on your layer.
2. You didn't set the position of `_moving` and `_pipes` - though it may seem unimportant, it is good to explicilty position all your nodes to not be suprised later on. A usefull thing here is the `` `CCPointZero ``.
3. I have never had any success whatsoever with reusing `CCSequences` like you do. It always turned out to be best to just create them when they are to be used and not worry about them later on.

Hope some of these will help!

Answer (score -1):

Try increasing the delay from 2.0f to 3.0f

```
CCDelayTime *delayForTwoSecs = CCDelayTime::create(3.0);
```